# Buttons interfering with each other on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, button

I am trying to make a button on my homepage of an app that will lead to a search page, that will have a handful more buttons leading to other pages. However, I used the same code from my activity main for the button in my second page (seachpage) and now when I run the code, my first button on my main page, when clicked it just shuts the app down. I don't even know how to approach this properly because I copied the same code, just changed the "findViewById" and the "startActivity" accordingly with their new labels. Any recommendation or help would be massively appreciated!

Activity main Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TranslateButton);

        if (yourButton == null) throw new AssertionError();
        yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchPage.class));
            }
        });
     }
}
```

Activity main xml for the button:

Secondary page (searchpage) Java code:

```
public class SearchPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_page);

        Button accommodationButton = (Button)     findViewById(R.id.accommodationButton);

        if (accommodationButton == null) throw new AssertionError();
        accommodationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SearchPage.this, Accommodation.class));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Secondary page xml for the button:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/accommodation"
        android:id="@+id/accommodationButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Thank you again for taking the time and consideration to read and/or respond to my question~!

Comment: Post the stacktrace, `activity_main.xml` and `activity_search_page.xml` please

Comment: for the main page: Java: package com.aid.travelers.myapplication;                    for the main page: XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                                  for the second page : Java: package com.aid.travelers.myapplication;
for the second page: XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"